# Javascript: How do I get the split() function in this script to work

Tags: javascript, arrays

Could some one help me with this please?

I have this function from another programmer:

```
function checkRequired(fieldList) {
    var field = null;
    var blankFields = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < fieldList.length; i++) {
        listItem = fieldList[i].split;
        fieldId = field[0];
        label = field[1];
        field = document.getElementById(fieldList[i].split("||")[0]);
        if (isVisible(field) && isBlank(field)) {
            blankFields[blankFields.length] = fieldList[i].split[1];
        }
    }
```

I am passing this json array to it:

```
var fieldList = new Array("'15||Project Requested By'","'18||Project Title'","'20||Banner Details'","'202||Flyer Details'","'2134||If Gl Code Not above'","'5862||Quantity'");
```

Using FB I see that the function errors out on this line `[listItem = fieldList[i].split;]`

I am not understanding exactly what the .split is doing and the problem it's causing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Update: image added showing where error occurs:
[image]

Comment: I do not see any JSON in your question.

Comment: That's not a JSON array... that's simply an array

Comment: I'd be extremely skeptical of this code; there are a number of major red flags. For one, a value is assigned to `listItem`, but it is never actually used. Second, that value is a function, even though `listItem` suggests that the variable is a value. Third, the first pass through involves accessing a `null` value as if it is an array. Three red flags is enough to rethink the whole method.

Comment: Also, the line `blankFields[blankFields.length] = fieldList[i].split[1];` is going to error out... please... just ditch this code and rewrite it... it's a hot mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the function should be something like this:

```
function checkRequired(fieldList) {
    var field = null,
        blankFields = [],
        listText, listItem, fieldId, label;

    for (var i = 0; i < fieldList.length; i++) {
        listText = fieldList[i];
        listText = listText.substring(1, listText.length - 1); // trim ' (single quote)
        listItem = listText.split("||");
        fieldId = listItem[0];
        label = listItem[1];
        field = document.getElementById(fieldId);

        if (isVisible(field) && isBlank(field)) {
            blankFields.push(label);
        }
    }

    return blankFields;
}
```

Assuming that isVisible() and isBlank() are defined somewhere.

Comment: yes those functions are defined elsewhere - let me give this a try - thank you - back shortly.

Comment: That worked - thank you - there is another issue, but I want to see if I can figure it out myself.  THANKS SO MUCH!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide `split` with a parameter that tells it what to split on.

Right now, you're simply assigning the `split` function itself to `listItem`; you're not calling it.

You probably mean

```
listItem = fieldList[i].split("||");
```

[MDN Docs for split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

### EDIT

On further inspection, you're not assigning anything to `field`, so it's equal to `null` at the point that you try to access it like an array. Thus, what you *probably* mean is:

```
 field = fieldList[i].split("||");
```

Comment: That is what I thought, but in his code he has the slit a few lines down [field = document.getElementById(fieldList[i].split("||")[0]);]

Comment: true, but in the first pass through the loop, the attempt to do `field[0]` is going to choke, because `field` is `null`

Comment: I add the pipes in the split(), but still get the error.  See debug image above.